# Is there an Arduino library that can take in a DD/MM/YYYY date and tell me what day of the week it is?

Tags: c, arduino, weekday, real-time-clock

I am making a Clock and I have got all the hardware figured out and I'm working on the software now. I have the exact date of a particular day, but I want the Arduino to be able to convert that into a day of the week. I have had a look online, but I can't seem to get any of the libraries to work. Does anyone have any easy to use code for this problem?

Comment: a simple google will give lots of simple ways to calculate day of week right away https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Sakamoto's_methods

Comment: All of this depends on in which format you get the output from the external RTC.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a library for that, you can use [Tomohiko Sakamoto's Algorithm](https://medium.com/@sunil01966/tomohiko-sakamotos-algorithm-finding-the-day-of-the-week-e168d34d8402) based on offsets:

```
/**
 * Sunday = 0 ... Saturday = 6
 */
int day_of_week(int day, int month, int year)
{
    static const int offset[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};

    year -= month < 3;
    return (year + year / 4 - year / 100 + year / 400 + offset[month - 1] + day) % 7;
}
```

or if you prefer:

```
/**
 * ISO 8601 date and time standard
 * Monday = 1 ... Sunday = 7
 */
int ISO_day_of_week(int day, int month, int year)
{
    static const int offset[] = {6, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4, 0, 3, 5, 1, 3};

    year -= month < 3;
    return (year + year / 4 - year / 100 + year / 400 + offset[month - 1] + day) % 7 + 1;
}
```

Comment: Notably, this code will execute godawfully slow on AVR. One of the few things it hates more than division is 16 or 32 bit integers. Switch all types involved to `uint8_t` where possible, then split the algorithm up in multiple lines. It's not a PC.